# A declaration of a variable name declares the type of value to be stored? A trick?

Tags: java

So, I have this true/false question in my computer science class (we're using Java):

> A declaration of a variable name declares the **type** of value to be
>   stored there.

(the word "type" was bold in the question)

Now, I know that when you declare a variable you must specify the type in Java because it is statically typed:

```
int x;
```

In that code, a variable with the name of `x` is declared, and we know it is of type `int`.

However the question mentioned the term "variable name". Technically, the name/identifier of the variable is not responsible for declaring the variable's type. The name doesn't even need to allude to the variable's type if the programmer chooses.

I was wondering what the right choice would be here. Would it be true or false? To me it seems rather ambiguous... what should I do?

Comment: I would think you're reading too far into it, though it shouldn't have said "name" to avoid confusion.  You can't "declare a variable name" without giving a type.

Comment: *"To me it seems rather ambiguous... what should I do?"* Ask the person who assigned the question to be more explicit. Any other answer to this question is merely our conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is specific: "A **declaration** of a variable name declares..." (emphasis mine)

If it said "A variable name declares..." you may be correct in assuming this to be a trick question. However, since the question specifically targets the declaration itself, the correct answer is *true*.

Comment: +1 In Java, you cannot *declare* a variable *name* independently of declaring the variable itself: you declare the variable, giving it a name. The professor is not trying to mess with you: his wording was just a little confusing.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No he is not messing declaring the variable name is correct because when you say `int x`, you are here declaring the variable name which is x and setting its type. The answer is true, but your remark is incorrect

Comment: I agree, it is implied that when declaring a variable the type is declared along with the name, thus making this question true.

Comment: You were right, the correct answer was true. It was what I was thinking anyways, but the inclusion of "name" raised some doubts. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

My take is that the question was inaccurate. You don't declare variable names - you declare variables, which have names. But it isn't certain. So you should circle both true and false, put a * next to the question, perhaps write out what your thoughts are, or talk to a TA or the teacher about it.

Answer (score 2):

> A declaration of a variable name

is not the variable name.

He meant that saying `int x` is declaring the variable type which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Since its not possible in Java to declare just a variable name without also mentioning a data type (try it and see), there is really no ambiguity to the question.  When you declare a variable, you are setting both its name and its type.